# Can I create an editable PDF with FPDF?

Tags: pdf, fpdf

I have no luck finding if I can create an editable form with FPDF. Is it possible? I would like to create a table with editable cells and be able to save it with changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by being "able to save it with changes" you mean being able to do so in acrobat reader, you are out of luck.

A pdf with such a property is called "reader enabled". Reader enabling a pdf includes adding a special electronic signature to it (a "usage right" signature) with a private key held by adobe. Thus, only adobe software (e.g. Adobe acrobat) can reader enable a pdf.

Comment: I just read " Yes, with Reader XI you can now fill out PDF forms by typing directly on the page or clicking through fillable form fields. Upgrading to Reader XI also lets you save fillable PDF forms to your desktop." in the Adobe faq at http://www.adobe.com/products/reader/faq.html - maybe makes your problem disappear?

Comment: yeah but I wanted to do it from FPDF, not from Acrobat.

Comment: Well, if I read that right, adobe reader xi does not require reader-enabling for saving filled forms anymore. Thus, if your users can easily be switched to reader xi (and if I don't misinterpret that faq entry), you won't have to do anything special in fpdf anymore.